# Has "High School DxD" Light Novel ended?

Tags: high-school-dxd

Has *High School DxD* light novel ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, *High School DxD* has ended with volume 25, but it will be followed by a direct sequel titled *Shin Highschool DxD* (Source: [afterword of Volume 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogwoS.png)).

So the series has not really ended, as a direct sequel, Shin DxD, will be covering the second half of the Azazel Cup arc. Its Volume 1 will essentially be Volume 26, just with a different label.